# explanation of es 6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Can anyone explain what the code is doing [here](https://github.com/e-schultz/ng-summit-redux/blob/ee9416096b9a0837810b6ad184fa91808e89933e/src/middleware/http/http-middleware.js#L14)

```
return () => next => action => {
  const callAPI = action[CALL_API];

  if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
    return next(action);
  }

  let { endpoint } = callAPI;
  const { types, bailout } = callAPI;
```

It is initially returning a function but I don't get why there are two further fat arrows after the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrow function has only one parameter, then the parameter around that is optional. You just need to have enough parenthesis to understand them better.

```
return () => (next) => (action) => {
```

it returns a function, which when invoked returns another function which accepts one parameter, `next`. Now when that function is invoked, it returns another function, which accepts another parameter `action`.

Answer (score 1):

That code can be rewritten like below,

```
return function() { 
   return function(next) { 
      return function(action) {
```

It seems that the outer function returns a function with parameter `next` and that returns another one function with parameter `action`. That code in the link that you given has not minified, but that seems to be obfuscated.